# R data.table: how to go from tibble to data.table to tibble back?

Tags: r, data.table, tibble

I use mainly tables in the *tibble* fromat from `tidyverse`, but for some steps, I use the `data.table` package. I want to see what is the best way of converting a *data.table* back to *tibble*?

I understand that `data.table` has some clever function [setDT](https://rdrr.io/rforge/data.table/man/setDT.html) and [setDF](https://rdrr.io/rforge/data.table/man/setDF.html) function, that convert from *data.frame* to *data.table* (and vice-versa) by reference, i.e. without making a copy.

But what if I wanted to convert back to *tibble*? Am I copying the data using `as_tibble` on the *data.frame* resulting from `setDT()`? Is there a clever way to use this, maybe using the `setattr()` from `data.table`?

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

iris_tib <- as_tibble(iris)

## some data.table operation
setDT(iris_tib)
setkey(iris_tib, Species)
iris_tib[, Sepal.Length.Mean := mean(Sepal.Length), by = Species]



## How to convert back to tibble efficiently?
setDF(iris_tib)
iris_tib_back <-  as_tibble(iris_tib)

## it looks like we were able to update by reference? Only rownames were (shallow) copied?
changes(iris_tib, iris_tib_back)
```

Comment: Your "some data.table operation" is very straightforward in the tidyverse right? Hadley has an interface to data.table that retains dplyr syntax if that's your preference: https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr Re your main question, maybe this answers it? (I have not tested.) https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1877#issuecomment-253864899

Comment: two great refs, thanks! The first is interesting and the second is... I think pretty much the answer I was looking for indeed! :-)

Comment: Ok, cool :) You can self-answer it (I won't answer since I don't have tibble installed and don't know how to confirm that the setattr trick achieves the desired result)

Comment: The issue is that I don't know myself that well how to ascertain result is correct haha, not sure to understand fully what `as_tibble()` does with the row.names. But I guess if I don't care too much about rownames, that should be fine

Answer (score 6):

As @Frank mentioned, this was discussed in a post [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1877#issuecomment-253864899). One possibility is to use the `setattr()` function, which set attributes *by reference*. Precisely:

```
setattr(x, "class", c("tbl", "tbl_df", "data.frame"))
```

And if there's a doubt about the original class:

```
old_class <- class(iris_tib)
setDT(iris_tib)
.... # bunch of data.table operatios
setDF(iris_tib)
setattr(iris_tib, "class", old_class)
```

This *seems* to do the necessary job converting back to a tibble.