# R data.table: using setDF() within does not seem to work (globally)?

Tags: r, data.table

I am using converting back and forth from *data.frame* to *data.table* using a workflow like: `setDT()` + some `data.table` operation + `setDF()` (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431288/r-data-table-how-to-go-from-tibble-to-data-table-to-tibble-back)). Using `setDF()` will correctly transform back my input into a *data.frame*.

However, when I use exactly the same code, but within a function, the input is not transformed back into an *data.frame* anymore after a `setDF()` call! I suspect this is a difference between transforming locally and globally, but I don't quite understand, and especially, don't see how to get my input back into a *data.frame* (`setDF()` outside would work obviously, but that's not the idea).

```r
library(data.table)
data(iris)

## using setDF outside of function
setDT(iris)
iris[, Sepal.Length.Mean := mean(Sepal.Length), by = Species]
setDF(iris)

class(iris)
#> [1] "data.frame"

## using setDF within a function
fo <- function(df){
  setDT(df)
  df[, Sepal.Length.Mean := mean(Sepal.Length), by = Species]
  setDF(df)
  df
}

res <- fo(iris)
class(iris)
#> [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Shouldn't you check `class(res)`  since that is where you are storing the returned object?

Comment: You are correct `res` is of the right class, but my target is to leave the class of the input unchanged, and as `setDF()` changes by reference, I hoped that would be the case!?

Comment: I think function creates its own copy of the object and doesn't update it by reference.

Comment: I would be surprised about! setDF+[]+setDF update by reference, and I don't think that behavior would depend on whether they are outside or within a function!? At least that's what print(lobstr::ref(df)) seems to indicate?

Comment: I distinctly remember that this used to be different but I can reproduce this as far back as data.table 1.9.6 (on R 3.3.0), which is the oldest version I still have installed. You should take this to the data.table issue tracker because AFAICS nothing should trigger a copy here.